# Stuck Thread when using JSCH scp on Weblogic Server on unix

Tags: servlets, ftp, zip, weblogic, jsch

I am using JSCH in my web application deployed on Weblogic server on Linux env to copy a file from Linux box. But I get the timeout

> Thread-489 "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '57' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'"

My JSCH code is as below:

```
        try
    {
```

..................

```
        JSch jsch=new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession("username", "hostname", 22);
            session.setPassword("password");
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("filename.trace");
    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
       String rfile= "filename.trace";


       log.debug("Remote File: "+rfile);

      String command="scp -f "+rfile;

      log.debug("Trace shell command: "+command);

      Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
      ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

      log.debug("Trace shell command set.");

      // get I/O streams for remote scp
      OutputStream out=channel.getOutputStream();
      InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

      channel.connect();
      log.debug("Trace shell command executed.");
      byte[] buf=new byte[1024];

      // send '\0'
      buf[0]=0; 
      out.write(buf, 0, 1); 
      out.flush();

      while(true){
    int c= checkAck(in);
        if(c!='C'){
      break;
    }

        // read '0644 '
        in.read(buf, 0, 5);

        long filesize=0L;
        while(true){
          if(in.read(buf, 0, 1)<0){
            // error
            break; 
          }
          if(buf[0]==' ')break;
          filesize=filesize*10L+(long)(buf[0]-'0');
        }

        String file=null;
        for(int i=0;;i++){
          in.read(buf, i, 1);
          if(buf[i]==(byte)0x0a){
            file=new String(buf, 0, i);
            break;
      }
        }

    log.debug("filesize="+filesize+", file="+file);

        // send '\0'
        buf[0]=0;
        out.write(buf, 0, 1); 
        out.flush();

        // read a content of lfile

         //fos=new FileOutputStream(prefix==null ? lfile : prefix+file);
        int foo;
        while(true){
          if(buf.length<filesize) foo=buf.length;
      else foo=(int)filesize;
          foo=in.read(buf, 0, foo);
          if(foo<0){
            // error 
            break;
          }
          zos.write(buf, 0, foo);
          filesize-=foo;
          if(filesize==0L) break;
        }
        //fos.close();

        //fos=null;

    if(checkAck(in)!=0){
      //System.exit(0);
        throw new Exception();
    }


        // send '\0'
        buf[0]=0;zos.write(buf, 0, 1); zos.flush();

        //in.close();
      } 
      zos.closeEntry();
      in.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      log.debug(e);
      e.printStackTrace();
      try{if(zos!=null)zos.closeEntry();}catch(Exception ee){throw new Exception(ee);}
    }
```

When I try to use a simplified method, the command is executed successfully but the file size is 0 byte.

```
           ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(remotefile);
       zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);         

       String command="scp -f "+remotefile;

       Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
       ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);



       InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
       channel.connect();

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        //log.debug("length:"+in.read(bytes));

        while ((length = in.read(bytes)) >= 0) 
        {
            log.debug("length:"+length);
            zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }

        //log.debug(""+);
        zos.flush();
        zos.closeEntry();
        in.close();``
```

Below are the env details
AppServer: Weblogic 10.3.4
Appserver : Linux
Remote file located on Linux box
Java version: 1.6

Any idea what is causing the issue?

Comment: How far along does your code get? Do you have a line number where it's stuck? Are you sure you're actually breaking out of your `while` loops and that they're not stuck infinitely

Comment: The code is stuck at

int c= checkAck(in);

Comment: According to this, you shouldn't be using that `checkAck` http://osdir.com/ml/java.jsch/2008-08/msg00003.html Although this guy had a similar issue http://osdir.com/ml/java.jsch/2008-10/msg00012.html

Comment: I removed checkAck and the code doesnt hang now. But the file size that I get is 0 bytes. 
I had get this working on my weblogic installed on my local windows env. 
Will the behavior be different on Linux env since we are calling native script?
Since it is a web application I am writing to ZipOutputStream, will that be an issue?

Comment: the actual error is 

'code'
]", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds. Stack trace:
Thread-564 "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '61' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" <alive, suspended, waiting, priority=1, DAEMON> {
    -- Waiting for notification on: com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream@1e23d780[fat lock]
    java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:288)

'code'